# Setting minimum size for tikz node using default unit length

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have two node styles with a minimum size set to 7mm and they look perfect:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{style1} = [circle,draw,fill=white,minimum size=7mm,font=\Large];
    \tikzstyle{style2} = [rectangle,draw,fill=white,minimum size=7mm,font=\Large];

    \node (node1) at (0,0)  [style1] {1};
    \node (node2) at (1,0)  [style2] {A};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But then I'd like to be able to scale the whole picture and have the minimum sizes scale accordingly (without having to set the scale parameter for every node style manually). Since the default unit length is 1cm, I figured I can change `minimum size=7mm` to `minimum size= 0.7` but then the rectangle appears smaller:

[image]

Setting `minimum size=20` gives the desired effect. It seems the units are not working the way I expect them to. What's going on here?

Comment: I'd look in the general direction of using a multiplier that you use everywhere, e.g. set some macro `\newcommand\multiplier{.5}` and use `\dimexpr14\multiplier` as well as `scale=\multiplier` as your minimum size.

Comment: `minimum size` is a dimension. If you omit the unit then `pt` will be inserted. That means `minimum size=.7` is the same as `minimum size=.7pt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can let the transformation apply to nodes via `transform shape` key.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        style1/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,minimum size=7mm,font=\Large},
        style2/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=white,minimum size=7mm,font=\Large},
        transform shape
]

\foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,4}{
\begin{scope}[scale=\x,yshift=2cm]
    \node (node1) at (0,0)  [style1] {1};
    \node (node2) at (1,0)  [style2] {A};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Nevermind the fonts, it got stuck from a different answer.